# How do I plot pandas time series data with minor and major xticks?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot pandas time series data, but when I do so there are no minor and major xticks. I expect the minor tick to be the month and the major tick to be the year.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(123456)

ts = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.random.randn(1500), "B": np.random.randn(1500), "C": np.random.randn(1500)}, index=pd.date_range("1/1/2019", periods=1500))
ts = ts.cumsum()

ax = ts.plot(figsize=(19.2, 10.8))
```

plot 1:

[image: plot 1]

To try to fix the issue I decided to use matplotlib year and month locators and formatters:

```py
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("\n%Y"))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%b"))
```

plot 2:

[image: plot 2]

As seen in the image above this results in the minor ticks not showing when there are major ticks. I next tried to use `x_compat=True` when plotting and doing `ax.minorticks_on()` but these made things worse. I don't know what next to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(bymonthday=-1))
```